# Can Katniss Everdeen read?

Tags: the-hunger-games

It seems on two occasions that Katniss either avoids or refuses to read a letter.
I noticed the last occasion was when Haymitch brings her a letter from Plutarch, but I then thought there was an earlier occasion when a letter concerning her was read out loud by another character.

Do we have any other indication of her literacy level (movie/book)? I haven't read the books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, she can.

In the first movie, she reads notes on [offerings](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Sponsorship) sent by Haymitch.

> In the book, Katniss receives bread from District 11, sleep serum, burn medicine, soup and lamb stew. In the movie, she receives burn medicine and soup.

In the books, she is given notes by other characters. For example, in the second book, before a filming session, Cinna

> He hands me a small stack of cards. “You'll read these off camera while they're filming the clothes. Try to sound like you care.”

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about that. But between reading a note and a letter...

Comment: @flap152 Maybe I misunderstood you. Doesn't reading a note imply she can read? In the movies, things are read to her to avoid having narration, or the viewer having himself to read.